# Prestashop 1.7 problem ContextErrorException Notice: Undefined index: children

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I warmly welcome,
I have a problem with prestashop 1.7
I have an error in debug mode
"(1/1) ContextErrorException
Notice: Undefined index: children "

list of errors:

in eab98ad8919fcf1a7e2060ceae8b91f113c7e76a_2.file.header.tpl.php line 206

at Block_13590726862cd1bd9bb9b01_51849864->callBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_13590726862cd1bd9bb9b01_51849864), object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 184

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyDevTemplate), object(Block_13590726862cd1bd9bb9b01_51849864))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 156

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->instanceBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'Block_13590726862cd1bd9bb9b01_51849864', 'header_top')
in eab98ad8919fcf1a7e2060ceae8b91f113c7e76a_2.file.header.tpl.php line 71

at content_62cd1bd9bc4ac2_80327757(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123

at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114

at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216

at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385

at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('file:_partials/header.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 0, false)
in 61c125e3b807fa6076d547b401ad2a2b499b8997_2.file.layout-both-columns.tpl.php line 212

at Block_183281634862cd1bd9b112a3_70427178->callBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_183281634862cd1bd9b112a3_70427178), object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 184

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyDevTemplate), object(Block_183281634862cd1bd9b112a3_70427178))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 156

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->instanceBlock(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'Block_183281634862cd1bd9b112a3_70427178', 'header')
in 61c125e3b807fa6076d547b401ad2a2b499b8997_2.file.layout-both-columns.tpl.php line 61

at content_62cd1bd9b1ef68_42789401(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123

at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114

at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216

at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385

at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl')
in dc2b5ee6561bcfebd8f8e5d132a01193130b473e_2.file.layout-full-width.tpl.php line 42

at content_62cd1bd9afca05_42528401(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123

at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114

at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216

at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385

at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl')
in 58db5a69d85b31209e76dfb57d466dbc594726e9_2.file.page.tpl.php line 33

at content_62cd1bd9ae24c7_65768053(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123

at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114

at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216

at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385

at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('page.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', 0, 3600, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116

at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyDevTemplate), 'page.tpl')
in ae8047eb3088e391dd195c5699ff8171d9532892_2.file.index.tpl.php line 33

at content_62cd1bd9ab45f5_36308973(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123

at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114

at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyDevTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216

at Smarty_Internal_Template->render(false, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 232

at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(object(SmartyDevTemplate), null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 116

at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('index.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, false, true, false)
in SmartyDev.php line 40

at SmartyDev->fetch('index.tpl', null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 683

at FrontControllerCore->smartyOutputContent('index.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 667

at FrontControllerCore->display()
in Controller.php line 312

at ControllerCore->run()
in Dispatcher.php line 515

at DispatcherCore->dispatch()
in index.php line 28

file code: eab98ad8919fcf1a7e2060ceae8b91f113c7e76a_2.file.header.tpl.php:

```
<?php
/* Smarty version 3.1.33, created on 2022-07-12 09:15:33
  from '/home/klient.dhosting.pl/compute/intimashop.eu/public_html/themes/PRS904/templates/_partials/header.tpl' */

/* @var Smarty_Internal_Template $_smarty_tpl */
if ($_smarty_tpl->_decodeProperties($_smarty_tpl, array (
  'version' => '3.1.33',
  'unifunc' => 'content_62cd1f952a94a2_81370207',
  'has_nocache_code' => false,
  'file_dependency' => 
  array (
    'eab98ad8919fcf1a7e2060ceae8b91f113c7e76a' => 
    array (
      0 => '/home/klient.dhosting.pl/compute/intimashop.eu/public_html/themes/PRS904/templates/_partials/header.tpl',
      1 => 1656021708,
      2 => 'file',
    ),
  ),
  'includes' => 
  array (
  ),
),false)) {
function content_62cd1f952a94a2_81370207 (Smarty_Internal_Template $_smarty_tpl) {
$_smarty_tpl->_loadInheritance();
$_smarty_tpl->inheritance->init($_smarty_tpl, false);
$_smarty_tpl->inheritance->instanceBlock($_smarty_tpl, 'Block_28906007762cd1f952618a7_25053245', 'header_banner');
?>


<!-- Messenger Wtyczka czatu Code -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <!-- Your Wtyczka czatu code -->
    <div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat">
    </div>

    <?php echo '<script'; ?>
>
      var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
      chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "102127579223683");
      chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
    <?php echo '</script'; ?>
>

    <!-- Your SDK code -->
    <?php echo '<script'; ?>
>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v14.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    <?php echo '</script'; ?>
>
    
<?php 
$_smarty_tpl->inheritance->instanceBlock($_smarty_tpl, 'Block_79092777462cd1f95262906_59658277', 'header_nav');
?>


<?php 
$_smarty_tpl->inheritance->instanceBlock($_smarty_tpl, 'Block_160617178762cd1f952638b2_43965769', 'header_top');
?>

<?php }
/* {block 'header_banner'} */
class Block_28906007762cd1f952618a7_25053245 extends Smarty_Internal_Block
{
public $subBlocks = array (
  'header_banner' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Block_28906007762cd1f952618a7_25053245',
  ),
);
public function callBlock(Smarty_Internal_Template $_smarty_tpl) {
?>

  <div class="header-banner">
      <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayBanner'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

  </div>
<?php
}
}
/* {/block 'header_banner'} */
/* {block 'header_nav'} */
class Block_79092777462cd1f95262906_59658277 extends Smarty_Internal_Block
{
public $subBlocks = array (
  'header_nav' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Block_79092777462cd1f95262906_59658277',
  ),
);
public function callBlock(Smarty_Internal_Template $_smarty_tpl) {
?>

  <nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hidden-sm-down">
          <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayNav1'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

        <div class="right-nav">
            <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayNav2'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="hidden-md-up text-xs-center mobile">
        <div class="float-xs-left" id="menu-icon">
          <i class="material-icons d-inline">&#xE5D2;</i>
        </div>
        <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_user_info"></div>
        <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_cart"></div>
        <div class="top-logo" id="_mobile_logo"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
<?php
}
}
/* {/block 'header_nav'} */
/* {block 'header_top'} */
class Block_160617178762cd1f952638b2_43965769 extends Smarty_Internal_Block
{
public $subBlocks = array (
  'header_top' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Block_160617178762cd1f952638b2_43965769',
  ),
);
public function callBlock(Smarty_Internal_Template $_smarty_tpl) {
?>

  <div class="header-top-up">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_logo">
        <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['urls']->value['base_url'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
" class="header-logo">
          <img class="logo img-responsive" src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['shop']->value['logo'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['shop']->value['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="left-logo">
          <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayLogoBefore'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

      </div>

      <div class="right-logo">
          <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayLogoAfter'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 position-static">
        <div class="row">

            <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayTop'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mobile_top_menu_wrapper" class="row hidden-md-up" style="display:none;">
        <div class="js-top-menu mobile" id="_mobile_top_menu"></div>
        <div class="js-top-menu-bottom">
          <div id="_mobile_currency_selector"></div>
          <div id="_mobile_language_selector"></div>
          <div id="_mobile_contact_link"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-categories">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Kategorie
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="category-list">
            <?php $_smarty_tpl->_assignInScope('categories', Category::getNestedCategories(2));?>
            <?php
$_from = $_smarty_tpl->smarty->ext->_foreach->init($_smarty_tpl, $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['categories']->value[2]['children'], 'category');
if ($_from !== null) {
foreach ($_from as $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value) {
?>
              <li data-depth="0">
                <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['link']->value->getCategoryLink($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['id_category'],$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['link_rewrite']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
">
                      <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>

                </a>
                <?php if ($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['children']) {?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
$_from = $_smarty_tpl->smarty->ext->_foreach->init($_smarty_tpl, $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['children'], 'category');
if ($_from !== null) {
foreach ($_from as $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value) {
?>
                          <li data-depth="1">
                            <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['link']->value->getCategoryLink($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['id_category'],$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['link_rewrite']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
">
                                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['category']->value['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>

                            </a>
                          </li>
                        <?php
}
}
$_smarty_tpl->smarty->ext->_foreach->restore($_smarty_tpl, 1);?>
                    </ul>
                <?php }?>
              </li>
            <?php
}
}
$_smarty_tpl->smarty->ext->_foreach->restore($_smarty_tpl, 1);?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <?php echo call_user_func_array( $_smarty_tpl->smarty->registered_plugins[Smarty::PLUGIN_FUNCTION]['hook'][0], array( array('h'=>'displayNavFullWidth'),$_smarty_tpl ) );?>

<?php
}
}
/* {/block 'header_top'} */
}
```

file code: header.tpl:

```
{**
 * 2007-2016 PrestaShop
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
 *
 * @author    PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
 * @copyright 2007-2016 PrestaShop SA
 * @license   http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
 *}
{block name='header_banner'}
  <div class="header-banner">
      {hook h='displayBanner'}
  </div>
{/block}

<!-- Messenger Wtyczka czatu Code -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <!-- Your Wtyczka czatu code -->
    <div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat">
    </div>

    <script>
      var chatbox = document.getElementById('fb-customer-chat');
      chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", "102127579223683");
      chatbox.setAttribute("attribution", "biz_inbox");
    </script>

    <!-- Your SDK code -->
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v14.0'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    
{block name='header_nav'}
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hidden-sm-down">
          {hook h='displayNav1'}
        <div class="right-nav">
            {hook h='displayNav2'}
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="hidden-md-up text-xs-center mobile">
        <div class="float-xs-left" id="menu-icon">
          <i class="material-icons d-inline">&#xE5D2;</i>
        </div>
        <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_user_info"></div>
        <div class="float-xs-right" id="_mobile_cart"></div>
        <div class="top-logo" id="_mobile_logo"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
{/block}

{block name='header_top'}
  <div class="header-top-up">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="hidden-sm-down" id="_desktop_logo">
        <a href="{$urls.base_url}" class="header-logo">
          <img class="logo img-responsive" src="{$shop.logo}" alt="{$shop.name}">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="left-logo">
          {hook h='displayLogoBefore'}
      </div>

      <div class="right-logo">
          {hook h='displayLogoAfter'}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 position-static">
        <div class="row">

            {hook h='displayTop'}
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mobile_top_menu_wrapper" class="row hidden-md-up" style="display:none;">
        <div class="js-top-menu mobile" id="_mobile_top_menu"></div>
        <div class="js-top-menu-bottom">
          <div id="_mobile_currency_selector"></div>
          <div id="_mobile_language_selector"></div>
          <div id="_mobile_contact_link"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-categories">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Kategorie
          <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="category-list">
            {assign var='categories' value=Category::getNestedCategories(2)}
            {foreach from=$categories[2].children item=category}
              <li data-depth="0">
                <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($category.id_category, $category.link_rewrite)}">
                      {$category.name}
                </a>
                {if $category.children}
                    <ul>
                        {foreach from=$category.children item=category}
                          <li data-depth="1">
                            <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($category.id_category, $category.link_rewrite)}">
                                {$category.name}
                            </a>
                          </li>
                        {/foreach}
                    </ul>
                {/if}
              </li>
            {/foreach}
{*          {debug}*}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    {hook h='displayNavFullWidth'}
{/block}
```

I am asking for help because I do not know where the error is

thank you

Comment: Most of the time, it means that your module is trying to display something that does not exist; the developer forgot to check if the required variable has any data. It looks like it comes from your menu module or something else that displays categories.